# Regex matching more than it should

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing this:

```
List<String> listOfLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

String regex = startMatch + "(.*)" + endMatch;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        listOfLinks.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Where regex has a value of:

```
class="thumb-link" href="(.*)" titl
```

I am getting this result :

```
http://www.sportscraft.com.au/longline-vest--9344961510736.html" title="Longline Vest "> <img class="alpha" src="http://demandware.edgesuite.net/sits_pod19/dw/image/v2/AAJZ_PRD/on/demandware.static/Sites-Sportscraft-Site/Sites-sc-master/default/v1427554286311/images/hi-res/1102031_black_a.jpg?sw=180&amp;sh=215&amp;sm=fit" alt="Longline Vest , BLACK, hi-res" title="Longline Vest , BLACK" height="214" /> <img class="beta" src="http://demandware.edgesuite.net/sits_pod19/dw/image/v2/AAJZ_PRD/on/demandware.static/Sites-Sportscraft-Site/Sites-sc-master/default/v1427554286311/images/hi-res/1102031_black_b.jpg?sw=180&amp;sh=215&amp;sm=fit" alt="Longline Vest , BLACK, hi-res
```

When all I want is:

```
http://www.sportscraft.com.au/longline-vest--9344961510736.html
```

What this means is, the first part of the regex `class="thumb-link"` is working fine. But the second part `" titl` is not stopping the first time it matches. It keeps going till it finds another occurence.

When I test this on http://myregexp.com/ with the same regex I get the correct result. I guess there is some option I need to set to make this "non-greedy" but not sure which, since I can't reproduce the error in a regex tester.

Comment: Non-greedy is `?`. So `href="(.*?)"`. You probably should not be parsing HTML with regexp, though. It's error prone. It's preferable to use an HTML parsing library.

Comment: @cbednarski - thanks. Thing is some of the content I need isn't in the HTML, it's in various JS scripts etc. Regex is proving to be very good overall. Just need to "clean the source html first" i.e. remove any whitespace more than 2 spaces long and remove line breaks.

Comment: @cbednarski  - thanks again that works - I don't know why I have so much trouble with regex every time.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the "correct" result in the regex tester, unless something was typed in incorrectly.  You don't give your original HTML, but I tried one that you might have been using, and it gave me the same (incorrect) thing you got from Java.

Comment: @ankur In the example case, someone could use single quotes e.g. `href='example.com'`. This is valid HTML but will break your regexp. An HTML parsing library will help you avoid such pitfalls.If you want to see the webpage as a browser does, it may be easier to actually use a browser via remote-control (phantom.js or selenium or similar).

Comment: @cbednarski each of the pages I'm working with has the same template i.e. it's auto generated with the same CMS, so I'm assuming that shouldn't be a problem. But lot's of testing is definitely required.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
String regex = "^(.*?[^ ]) .*?";//remove ^, i have tried on your input string.
Output:
[http://www.sportscraft.com.au/longline-vest--9344961510736.html"]
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought the issue was with Java regex not regex. @cbednarski's solution works well. But will give this a go too